# firebird и mysql

Tags: firebird, mysql

firebird и mysql на одной машине дерутся или мирно сосуществуют?

Answer (score 2):

На уровне системы это два разных серверных приложения. Отдают трафик по разным портам. По умолчанию для MySQL - 3306, для Firebird - 3050. Мирно сосуществуют.

Answer (score 1):

Мирно сосуществуют.